# Checking sharedpreference before App starts

Tags: android

I want to check `SharedPreferences` before my app starts. I want to check whether a value in is true or false and depending on that I want to start different activities (if value is true, I want to start one activity; if it is false, I want to start second activity). How to check it before showing my apps first screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onCreate method first get the sharedpreference value .

if its true then set the content view i.e

```
 if(sharedpreference_value == true) { 
   setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
 }

 else {
   finish();
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

> i want to check shared preference before my app starts

By definition, that is not possible. If your app has not started, your code is not running, and so your code cannot check `SharedPreferences`.

> If value is true i want to start one activity if it is false i want to start second activity.how to check it before showing my apps first screen?

Have your activity handle one case (e.g., `true`) itself. In `onCreate()`, check `SharedPreferences`, and if the value is `false`, call `startActivity()` to launch the other activity, then `finish()` to get rid of the current one (since it is no longer needed).

Or, have only one activity, but two different fragments, and load the proper fragment based upon the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: +1 for the fragment solution. It's more elegant than chaining activities together.

Comment: @Mario: Then you should go with the fragment solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your starting activity, do your decision in `onCreate`, and excute appropriate activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate() method check if the value in the shared Preference is true of false

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
boolean check = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Check",false);
Intent intent;       
if(check){
intent = new Intent(this, First.class);
else
intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

But keep in mind that the boolean value `check` should exist in the Shared Preferences otherwise it will always return false.